# How to use 'let' and 'map' to simplify a recursive function in racket?

Tags: recursion, lambda, racket

I'm stuck on a practice problem that requires me to simplify a recursive function by using 'let' and 'map'.

The original function (biggest-number) takes a list as input and outputs the biggest number in that list. (ex: (biggest-number (list 1 2 3)) -> 3
Here's the code for the original function.

```
(define (biggest-number list1)
  (cond
    [(empty? (rest list1)) (first list1)]
    [(cons? (rest list1))
     (if (> (first list1) (biggest-number (rest list1)))
         (first list1)
         (biggest-number (rest list1)))]))
```

I'm just having trouble finding a lambda function to use map with.
This is what I have so far, which is very wrong and worsened the original.

```
(define (simple-max list1)
  (cond
    [(empty? (rest list1)) (first list1)]
    [(cons?  (rest list1))
    (let ((test (lambda (number) (if (> number (simple-max (rest list1)))
                                number
                                (simple-max (rest list1))))))
      (map test list1))]))
```

I want to start by finding a lambda function that can replace the 'if' statement, and then use 'let' to assign a variable to the lambda equation. Can someone help me with the thinking process to get the lambda function?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how you would use `map` to simplify a [catamorphic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catamorphism) (i.e. a function which folds a data structure into a value). In your case, you are folding a list into the biggest number of that list:

```hs
biggest-number :: [Int] -> Int
```

You can't use `map` because map is a structure preserving operation:

```hs
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

You need to fold the list into a value using an operation such as [`foldl`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldl%29%29):

```hs
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

This is how I would write it:

```
(define (max x y) (if (> x y) x y))

(define (biggest-number list) (foldl max (car list) (cdr list)))
```

Simple and succinct.

Comment: Thanks! I understand map a lot better now. I'll keep tinkering with the problem!